# Query regarding django forms

Tags: django, django-forms

I'm trying to make a form using Django which consists of a question and different possible answers(radio button options).
So my question is how can I give weightage(score) to different options and store it in the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add [choices](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#choices) in the models

For example:

```
class Answer(models.Model):

    A = 1.00
    B = 1.70
    C = 2.00
    D = 2.30

    ANS_CHOICES = (
        (A, 'Option A'),
        (B, 'Option B'),
        (C, 'Option C'),
        (D, 'Option D'),
    )
    answer = models.DecimalField(null = True, blank = True, verbose_name = "Choices", decimal_places = 2, max_digits = 3, choices = ANS_CHOICES)
```

Hence the answer choices will be Option A,B,C and D and on selecting the choice, respective value will be assigned. FYI: By default, the answer field will be a dropdown